# Referring to Values in a loop in JAVASCRIPT

Tags: javascript, loops

The following is all Javascript EFS which is javascript but adapted to stocks and trading software.

So in following example: 
high() is simply the High of price in a 1 minute bar. All bars process a High and Low (price for that minute) every minute.

Okay i have figured out how to use loops. However, i am having difficulty in accessing values within the loop i created e.g.

```
var Source2 = high();
 var vValue2   = Source2.getValue(15);

for (h = -15; h < 0; h++)       {  
     vValue2 = Math.max(vValue2, Source2.getValue(-h)); 

 if (vValue2 == Source2.getValue(-h))        { 
        barIndex2 = getCurrentBarIndex()-h; 
       }
}
```

Now lets assume this is all fine and it returns me the values (in this case the Highest high looking forward 15 bars from entry point). However, i now wish to make conditions for the loop to process (all for backtesting purposes) such as:

- I want to return (vValue2 +1) e.g. 'vValue2' has been returned as the highest high (15 bars) and now i want to know the value of 'vValue2 +1 bar' even if this is not the highest bar.
- Is there a way for the loop only to return values if multiple conditions are met such as: 
  i. Return the first Highest high of the 15 bars (lets say 'h') IF the bar ('h' +1) of this return value has a LOW which is less than the LOW of ('h') && ('h'+2), ('h'+3), ('h'+4), all have High less than ('h').

Basically i want to add multiple IF conditions to start a loop?? Or am i supposed to add the IF conditions after a loop has returned its values???

- I am not sure if the things i require are possible or must i use loop after loop to get the desired results.

Answer (score 1):

You can use multiple conditions in your `for` loop like this:

`for (h = -15; (h < 0 && something == somethingElse); h++)`

You can also `break` out of a loop with something like this:

```
for (h = -15; h < 0; h++)       { 
    if(blah == 1)break;  // breaks out of loop completely
}
```

Comment: So can i reference the value h+1 in as a condition?? So something like this would work:  (h=-15; (h<0 && (h+1(low)<h); h++. I dont think this will work in my example because first i need to find the Value (Low) of (vValue2 +1) then this must be compared at each count in the loop. The loop would not know what the value of (h+1(low) is until the loop returns vValue2????

Comment: The condition part of the for loop is evaluated each time the loop runs.  I'm not sure what your `low` function is doing, but here is an example of how you could have multiple conditions in the `for`  http://jsfiddle.net/4Sn6q/